# How do I reset without using the reset button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**My project:**

I'm doing the bookmark section in the Yandex Browser.

---

Image of my project:
[image]

---

I want to reset the two entered values ​​when I click the button. (I don't want to do that with the reset button. I don't want to use the form label.)

---

**My codes:**

```
    $("#add").click(function(){
        $("#siteName").val(" ");
        $("#siteURL").val(" ");
    });
```

Although he works here, he doesn't work in my project.

Since the codes are too long, I uploaded them here. [Click to reach.](https://codepen.io/guldus/pen/MdYvJG?editors=0010)

Comment: Use the form's `.reset()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the addBookmark function on click, you can reset the values there.

```
function addBookmark(){
// set variables
var siteName = document.getElementById("siteName").value;
var siteURL = document.getElementById("siteURL").value;
document.getElementById("siteName").value = '';
document.getElementById("siteURL").value = '';
```

(EDIT)
or with JQuery

```
function addBookmark(){
// set variables
var siteName = document.getElementById("siteName").value;
var siteURL = document.getElementById("siteURL").value;
$("#siteName").val('');
$("#siteURL").val('');
```

Comment: probably easier for him to transition to `document.querySelector('#siteName');` rather than getElementById since it's pretty simlar to jquery. selector-wise

Comment: Yeah, he is already using the getElementById selector inside that function, but I agree that it's clearer with jquery. I'll update the post with jquery solution.

Answer (score 1):

Then you need import jquery to your project.

```html
<input id="siteName" name="siteName"><input id="siteURL" name="siteURL"><button id="add">Click Me</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <script type="application/javascript">
    $("#add").click(function(){
        $("#siteName").val("");
        $("#siteURL").val("");
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: please stop using the `type` attribute if you're using javascript
https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics-scripting.html#element-attrdef-script-type